# Compactly supported de Rham cohomology groups of $M\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, de-rham-cohomology

My question is regarding a proof of the fact that $H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})\approx H_{c}^{k}(M)$ whenever $M$ is an oriented $m$-manifold whose compactly supported de Rham cohomology groups $H_{c}^{k}(M)$ are finite dimensional. The proof uses Poincaré duality [$H^{k}(M)\approx(H_{c}^{m-k}(M))^{\ast}$] and is straightforward:
$$H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})\approx H^{m+n-k-n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})\approx H^{m-k}(M)\approx H_{c}^{k}(M)$$
However, I don't get why $\dim H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})<\infty$ so that $H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})\approx (H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n}))^{\ast}\approx H^{m+n-k-n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})$. I've tried defining an injective linear map $H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})\to H_{c}^{k}(M)$ in order to show that $\dim H_{c}^{k}(M)<\infty $ implies $\dim H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})<\infty$, but I did not succeed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you start from the right, where you know it is finite dimensional, and work toward the left? Then everything is known to be finite dimensional. (I do think the middle two terms needs *, though.)

Comment: @Threeaggies the middle isomorphisms comes from the fact that $M\times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $M$ are homotopy equivalent. Starting from the right, I end up with $H_{c}^{k}(M)\approx (H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n}))^{\ast}$ and this shows that $\dim(H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n}))^{\ast}<\infty$. After looking at this I think I solved my problem: using the fact that there is a natural injection $V\to V^{\ast\ast}$ would imply $\dim H_{c}^{k+n}(M\times \mathbb{R}^{n})<\infty$, right?

Comment: I thought you would get $H^k_c(M)\cong (H^{m-k}(M))^*\cong (H^{m-k}(M\times R^n))^* \cong H_c^{k+n}(M\times R^n)$ directly.